# How to check values in array in object

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I am busy with jasmine unit testing. But I get errors. I have some problems with more values in array. And I don't understand that.

I have this as unit test code:

```
  component.portfolio = {
            learningPath: [
                {
                    id: '2345',
                    metaLines: ['sbu tekst', '29 maart 2019'],
                    title: 'mock name',
                    titleLink: `${learningPathDetailsLink}/2345`,

                },
                {
                    id: '23567',
                    metaLines: ['sbu tekst', '1 april 2019'],
                    title: 'mock name',
                    titleLink: `${learningPathDetailsLink}/23567`,

                },


            ],
        } as any;

        // Assert
        expect(component.cards).toEqual([
            new CardModel({ id: '2345', metaLines: ['sbu tekst', '29 maart 2019'], title: 'mock name', titleLink: `${learningPathDetailsLink}/2345` }),
            new CardModel({ id: '23567', metaLines: ['sbu tekst', '1 april 2019'], title: 'mock name', titleLink: `${learningPathDetailsLink}/23567` }),
        ]);
        expect(formatPipeSpy.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual(['30 maart 2019', resources.begindatumTitel]);
        expect(formatPipeSpy.calls.argsFor(1)).toEqual(['30 maart 2019', resources.afrondDatumTitel]);
```

But then I get this as errors:

```
Expected $[0].metaLines[0] = undefined to equal 'sbu tekst'.
Expected $[0].metaLines[1] = undefined to equal '29 maart 2019'.
Expected $[0].title = undefined to equal 'mock name'.
Expected $[0].titleLink = 'undefined/2345' to equal 'test/learningpath-details/2345'.
Expected $[1].metaLines[0] = undefined to equal 'sbu tekst'.
Expected $[1].metaLines[1] = undefined to equal '1 april 2019'.
Expected $[1].title = undefined to equal 'mock name'.
Expected $[1].titleLink = 'undefined/23567' to equal 'test/learningpath-details/23567'.
Error: Expected $[0].metaLines[0] = undefined to equal 'sbu tekst'.
Expected $[0].metaLines[1] = undefined to equal '29 maart 2019'.
Expected $[0].title = undefined to equal 'mock name'.
Expected $[0].titleLink = 'undefined/2345' to equal 'test/learningpath-details/2345'.
Expected $[1].metaLines[0] = undefined to equal 'sbu tekst'.
Expected $[1].metaLines[1] = undefined to equal '1 april 2019'.
Expected $[1].title = undefined to equal 'mock name'.
Expected $[1].titleLink = 'undefined/23567' to equal 'test/learningpath-details/23567'.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9890/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/components/src/portfolio/portfolio-details/portfolio-details.component.spec.ts:116:33)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9890/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/E:/Projects/VLR/Web/vlrworkspace/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1429:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.push.../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9890/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/E:/Projects/VLR/Web/vlrworkspace/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
Expected $[0] = undefined to equal '30 maart 2019'.
```

I realy don't unsestand that. Because what is wrong with:

```
  metaLines: ['sbu tekst', '29 maart 2019'],
```

This are the two values or not?

Comment: can somebody help me?

Comment: Where is a value assigned to `learningPathDetailsLink`?